# Javascript recursion onEvent on Code.org

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with a project for my AP CompSci class. We're supposed to create programs using the App Lab on code.org. The problem is every time I stop the timed loop, the resulting number gets printed more than once after the first stop. I'm pretty sure I didn't add a recursion element so it's odd. Is there something wrong with the code or is it something else?

https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/KeB7MbUhChuQbQ6HiAA7GeED7Y9trOEJJ9GXld7lOfc

Edit:

```
onEvent("stop3", "click", function(){
 hideElement("stop3");
 stopTimedLoop();
 showElement("return3");
 var points = Math.round(10*(15-(time/100)));
 console.log(time);
 score = score + points;
 update();
});
```

The recursion happens after the first time the button is clicked. On the second click the function would rerun after completing the update. On face value the code should only run once per click, but it runs according to how many previous clicks have been made. I can't tell if its a server side problem or something wrong with the editor. The problem seems to be isolated to this function, but there is no recursion so I'm starting to wonder if there is a problem with it server side.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: **Please consider** _Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed._ **from:** https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: The teach already checked it and said that it should run correctly, yet every time an onEvent is called a recursion happens if you try it again.